# Deriving First Success Expectation with linearity property of expectation?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

I'm a newbie studying probability.

Let $X$ be random variables distributed as Geometric Distribution:
$X \sim \text{Geom}(p)$.

Let $Y$ be random variables distributed as First Success Distribution:
$Y \sim \text{FS}(p)$.

I know how to calculate the Geometric expectation:

$$E(X) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kq^kp = pq\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kq^{k-1} = pq\frac{1}{(1-q)^2} = \frac{p}{q}$$

and the First Success expectation:
$$E(Y) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kq^{k-1}p = p\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kq^{k-1} = p\frac{1}{(1-q)^2} = \frac{1}{p}$$

But in the book there is another way to derive the formula for $E(Y)$.

it says: "Since we can write $Y \sim \text{FS}(p)$ as $Y = X + 1$ where $X \sim \text{Geom}(p)$, we have $E(Y) = E(X+1)=\frac{q}{p}+1=\frac{1}{p}$."

I know that both method arrive at the same formula but why the second derivation is valid?

is it because of the linearity property of the expectation? such as $E(X+Y) = E(X) + E(Y)$ and in this case it is $E(Y) = E(X+1) = E(X) + E(1) = \frac{q}{p}+1.$ 
I didn't know that the linearity property also valid for the constant 1 and if it is valid what is the formal calculation of $E(1)$ ?? why is $E(1) = 1$ ???

Can someone also make correction on my $E(Y)$ calculation above because $k$ starts from $1$: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kq^{k-1}p $ , does is make difference from the summation of Geometric expectation which starts at $k=0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, if the second summation would start at $0$ you would get the same result:
$$
k\cdot q^{k-1}\cdot p = 0, \quad \text{if} \ k=0.
$$
Concerning $E[1]=1$. You can think about a random variable $Z$ which always take value $1$, so $P(Z=1)=1$. The name random variable is not so appropriate here, because $Z$ is always equal to one and hence not random, but anyway. From a mathematical perspective a random variable is only a measurable function:
$$
Z: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R: \omega \mapsto 1.
$$ 
Then clearly $E[Z]=1$, since $Z$ can only take the value $1$.
This is what is meant by $E[1]$.
Using this definition of $E[1]$ you get the results you need and the linearity holds also in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great answer ^^. Additional question, can I also think of E(1) as the algebraic definition of Expectation: E(X) which is the summation of the value of support of X multiply with the probability of that value. so for the E(1) the probability is 1 and the value is 1 which is 1 * 1 = 1. Additional question is when E(3) for example, what is the value of E(3), is it 3*1 = 3 ??? because the value is 3 multiply with the probability which is 1 ? Am I understand correctly?

Comment: can you also explain the omega in plain english? I do not use to the Z: omega things ^^"

Comment: @user3270418 $\Omega$ is the usual symbol used for the *sample space* ; the set of all outcomes. $~$ The expression reads that the random variable $Z$ is a function that maps the sample space $\Omega$ to the real numbers $\Bbb R$ and specifically that it maps any outcome, $\omega$, to the value of $1$. $~$ ($Z$ has a degenerate distribution.)

Comment: For any constant $c$, by the definition of expectation and the Law of Total Probability: $\mathsf E(c) ~=~ \sum_{x} c\cdot \mathsf P(X{=}x)~=~ c~~$  Thus the expected value of a constant, is that constant.